# Chip Group listener change chip position when fragment recreate

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-chips

I'm creating a chip programmatically. The chips are created but when the app stops *(not destroyed)* and re-opens, the position of the chip changes in the chip Group Listener.

Here is my code:

```
private lateinit var playlist: Array<Pair<String, String>>

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
for (item in playlist){
    createChip(item.first)
}}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
chip_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chipGroup, position ->
    for (i in 0 until chipGroup.childCount){
        val chip = chipGroup.getChildAt(i)
        chip.isClickable = chip.id != chipGroup.checkedChipId
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}}

fun createChip(name: String){
    val chip = Chip(chip_group.context)
    chip.text = name
    chip.isClickable = true
    chip.isCheckable = true
    chip.isCheckedIconVisible = false
    chip_group.addView(chip)
}
```

I'm expecting the chip to have the same position when the app re-opens, but instead the position increases.

Comment: you can add tag to chip `chip.tag=123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `id` with `position`.
`onCheckedChanged(ChipGroup group, int checkedId)` is interface method called when the checked chip has changed.

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
var index=0
for (item in playlist){
    createChip(item.first,index++)
}}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
chip_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chipGroup, id ->
    for (i in 0 until chipGroup.childCount){
        val chip = chipGroup.getChildAt(i)
        chip.isClickable = chip.id != chipGroup.checkedChipId
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}}

fun createChip(name: String,index:Int){
    val chip = Chip(chip_group.context)
    chip.text = name
    chip.isClickable = true
    chip.isCheckable = true
    chip.isCheckedIconVisible = false
    chip.id=index //maybe you can use tag
    chip_group.addView(chip)
}
```